# Data read from linked server returns different data-type on production server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2012, linked-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server grabbing data from a linked Oracle server inside a SP.

On my development server, EF6 insists the SP is returning a `double` datatype for one of the columns, but in prod, it insists the same column is a `decimal`.

The SQL Server version is slightly different:

- Prod: 11.0.5582.0
- Dev : 11.0.5613.0

There are no (obvious) differences in how the linked servers are configured (i.e. I've compared the connection properties in SSMS).

Being a new feature, the production database has very few (zero, even) rows in the database, while the dev server has many. I have a feeling that might be related, because I recall having to change the datatype in the middle of development (though I didn't think much of it at the time).

What might be the problem here?

Comment: There's potential that the data being returned fits within what your EF defines as a decimal, rather than a double. IT could mean that the level of precision being returned is higher than you expect (something greater than 16 significant figures). Have you tried casting the results to something smaller, like a numeric(10,2)?

Comment: @Nic The actual data in the development database are whole numbers in a narrow range of about 10 and 10,000. That is definitely the workaround that comes to mind.

Comment: As it turns out, the Oracle column is defined as a NUMBER with no precision or scale, which causes the numbers to be stored as floating-point. Seems like there might be a bug somewhere where (like me) something is expecting a NUMBER column to always return something decimal-like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The observed difference in behavior is due to the difference in patch levels between the two servers.

Per the resolution of [KB3051993](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3051993), which is included in Cumulative Update 6 For SQL Server 2012 SP2):

> After you apply this fix, NUMBER values with unknown precision/scale
>   are treated as double values with OLE DB provider. If the precision is
>   important and the range of the values is not large enough, you can
>   enable the new Trace Flag 7311 that would start treating such values
>   as numeric (38, 10).